Export COM Interface for class from another assembly
I have two projects, Server and ServerCOMInterop. I have defined some classes in the Server project and I have imported them in ServerCOMInterop. Now I want to create a COMInterface for the ServerCOMInterop but the classes from Server are not available when using the interface.
Just to make this more clear, here is some code:
// This is in the Server project
namespace Server {
  [Guid("5c2f4d41-9b23-435b-8245-b180eb350a26")]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public class Point {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
  }
}

// This is in the server-com-interop-project
using Server;
namespace ServerCOMInterop {
  // This class and its methods show up just fine, ...
  [Guid("43dbba1c-5bb5-4df0-87f1-5f3bf9729482")]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public class Operations {

    ...

    // but the Point type does not
    public int LengthSquared(Point point) {
      return point.X * point.X + point.Y * point.Y;
    }

    ...

  }
}

In case this is relevant, I am using .Net Framework 4.5 and trying to use the COM interface from VB6.
I would have expected the Point type to be available just like e.g. the Operations class; however trying to create a new Point from VB6 or determining the type of point when it is returned / expected as a parameter fails both when running the code and when using code completion.
I have tried setting "Register for COM-Interop" on the Server-project to true aswell, but this did not have any effects.
Are there any other things I need to do to be able to access Point through COM or is sharing a type from another project through COM simply not possible?

Have you tried public int LengthSquared(Server.Point point) ? And of course also referencing Server in the VB project.
